# Slack: how to display a intRAnet hyper link as its title?

Tags: hyperlink, intranet, slack

It seems Slack does not support

```
<https://site|title>
```

or

```
[title](https://site)
```

I know Slack can automatically show the link's title if you just input a link itself:

```
https://www.google.com
```

The Slack will show you with its title:

[image]

This seems smart, however, it need the link be a public link which can be accessed from Slack server,

so, what about you enter a private link?

```
http://192.168.1.10
```

You'll just get a link without title;
[image]

How can I specify title of the link?

Answer (score 0):

Slack does support `<https://site|title>` format. However I noticed it only works if a bot user/app posts a message to a channel. If you try to type it out yourself it won't work.